# Hide Lenovo Yoga 10 Tablet (Android) system bar

Tags: root-access, tablet, lenovo-yoga

I purchased yoga 10 tablet few days ago for a special purpose/apps. For that apps i need to run that in full screen. But i can't hide the system bar. By system bar i means bottom bar on the screen where it shows back/menu etc button.

On my other tabs (not lenovo) it works fine.

steps:

1. i root the device/tablets
2. then install and use below apps.

FullScreen! Android Apps

but on my lenovo after i root when i try that apps it crash/hung the tablet. Only a restart can again run the tablets

On lenovo i use farma root app to root the device....

so, can any one help me to solve my issue. ?

i really need to hide that system bar

Comment: That is usually called the "navigation bar". If you are running KitKat you can enable your app in "Immersive Mode" which will hide the nav bar for you. Alternatively you can force fullscreen in applications you write, using the appropriate code. The final option would be to find an Xposed module that hides them, or forces immersive mode on the device I guess.

Comment: @RossC, thanks for your reply sir. my android OS is 4.4.2. but i don't know how to enable/run app in "Immersive Mode". for your kind information the app i need to run is not my own developed. It is developed by someone else. can you help please?

thanks again..

Comment: As I said, look into Xposed installer, and any Xposed modules that will force Immersive mode, it's the only way I can think of. You'll need rooted devices, but there are modules that allow you to use Immersive mode on specific apps. Gravity Box has this feature afaik. BUT in immersive mode, clicking the bottom of the screen will display the nav bar again, and then it fades away. Try Google Books if you want to see it in action!

Comment: @RossC, thanks again for your support. however sir, xPosed need root access... thought i root with farma root but i heard farmaroot can't root properly 4.4.2. So, can you give me resource to root my lenovo tablet properly? please?